# How to enable fcbkcomplete in dialog Jquery

Tags: jquery

I use autocomplete plugin: http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html

its work fine in page, but search result not showing when i place in dialog box (iam use Jquery UI).

Please somebody help me...
i have change z-index in style.css but this problem not gone.

```
<select id="select1" name="select1">
  <option value="test1">test1</option>
  <option value="test3">test2</option>

  <option value="test4">test3</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#select1").fcbkcomplete();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sory, i just finished my problem, fcbkcomplete() can show on dialog if the dialog properties are set autoOpen = true;